# crashed when touch two sprites at the same time(cocos2d-iphone)

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

The app will crash when two sprites are touched at the same time.

```
-(void)addEnemy
{
  enemy = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"enemy.png"];
  enemy.position = ccp(winsize.width / 2,  winsize.height / 2);
  [spriteSheet addChild:enemy];
  [spritetiles addObject:enemy]; //spritetiles is NSMutableArray
}
```

touch code

```
-(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
   CGPoint location = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace: touch];
   for (CCSprite *target in [spriteSheet children]) {
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(target.boundingBox, location)) {
        [target stopAllActions];
        [spriteSheet removeChild:target cleanup:YES];
        [spritetiles removeObject:target];
    }
  }
}
```

if I touch any one of the sprite, there's no error, but if i touch two sprites(sometime some sprites' position is nearby), the app will crash, at the code line "if (CGRectContainsPoint(target.boundingBox, location)) {", so how can I fix it? thanks

Comment: dont show part of your code if you want help. Where does 'location' come from in ccTouchesBegan, and what is an _bomb in addEnemy ?

Comment: @YvesLeBorg sorry for that, i have updated the code now, please take a look.

Comment: hmmm ... beware of modifying an array ( [spriteSheet children] ) while iterating it.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg Can you explain it why? and how can I fix it? many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated**

Use reverseEnumerator in order to iterate through an array when you may need to remove elements as part of the for loop:

```
-(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace: touch];

    for (CCSprite *target in [spriteSheet.children reverseObjectEnumerator]) {
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(target.boundingBox, location)) {
            [target stopAllActions];
            [spriteSheet removeChild:target cleanup:YES];
            [spritetiles removeObject:target];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @yegomo dont forget to upvote the answer too for a proper thank you :)

Comment: no no no no actually, all you really need is to use the reverseEnumerator. It is legal to remove the currently iterated object in an array when enumerating in reverse.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D how to use reverseEnumerator? I googled, but there is no info about how to use reverseEnumerator.

Comment: for (id x in [array reverseObjectEnumerator]) {..} ... in this case it would be [spriteSheet.children reverseObjectEnumerator]

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Thanks. I've incorporated your simpler solution into my answer.